# How to check for existing entry in a Spring reactive application?

Tags: mono, save, repository, crud, reactive

I'm trying to write a simple REST API in a Reactive way (using R2DBC) with all CRUD operations on a database storing books. With one of the defined endpoints it should be possible to save a book to the database. So I have written the following code to save a book to the database:

```
public Mono<Book> saveBook(Mono<Book> book) throws ResourceAlreadyExistsException {
    return book.doOnNext(b -> log.info("Save book with title " + b.toString()))
               .flatMap(b -> bookRepository.findByTitle(b.getTitle()))
               .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> bookRepository.saveAll(book).next()))
               .flatMap(b -> Mono.error(
                        new ResourceAlreadyExistsException(String.format("Book already exists for provided title :: %s" , book.getTitle()))));              
}
```

So I first check if the book title already exists in the database. If the book does not exists, the switchIfEmpty will be executed, and the book will be stored. But after the switchIfEmpty, the flatMap is also always called! In the above code, even when a book is stored successfully, an error will be thrown in the last flatmap. Obviously I am doing something wrong here...

What I am trying to achieve in my reactive application is the following:

1. Check if the book title already exists in the database
2. If not, save the book to the database
3. If the book already exists, throw an exception

I hope someone can help to write this piece of code in a clean and efficient way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most effective way to do it is by using constraints in your database. If you set the title as a unique column and you try to save another book with the same title, the database will throw the exception.

The only thing you have to do then is to "catch" this exception with the onErrorResume method and convert it to your custom  "ResourceAlreadyExists" exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion! I just didn't think about using the 'unique' keyword on the database. This was helpful!